# UICollectionView multiple cell types in the same section using Compositional layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have two Type of cell "ProductCell" and "NoImageProductCell".
The data is provided by an API so I have no control over the type of product that I will get(with or without image).

How to use Compositional Layout to show both types in the same section with different cell size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom that let you size each item that belong to a group separately.

```
    let items = self.dataSource.snapshot().itemIdentifiers(inSection: 2)
                let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.custom(layoutSize: groupSize) { (env) -> [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem] in
                var customItems = [NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem]()
                items.forEach { (object) in
                    switch object.imageURL {
                    case .none:
                        //calculate frame and append item
customItems.append(NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem(frame: yourFrame))
                    case .some(_):
                        //calculate frame and append item
customItems.append(NSCollectionLayoutGroupCustomItem(frame: yourFrame))
                    }
                }
                return customItems
            }
```

Comment: Where you write this code? in method where we define our compositional layout?

Comment: @AhmedShendy Yes

Comment: And then did you add the items to a group like normal?  or how did you add items to the layout?  Thx

Comment: @devjme the items are already added to the group via the itemProvider. You just need to add the group to section and then add the section to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Is anyone be here, I would suggest u to try that

```
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
        heightDimension: .estimated(128)
    )
)

let item2 = NSCollectionLayoutItem(
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
        heightDimension: .estimated(36)
    )
)

let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(
    layoutSize: NSCollectionLayoutSize(
        widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1),
        heightDimension: .estimated(128)
    ),
    subitems: [item, item2]
)
```

And that's all. I guess compos layout automatically calculate height for .estimated() for both item and item2 and apply that calculation.